# Dagger 2 and use of @Singleton

Tags: java, dagger-2

I have inherited a Java web service project that is using Dagger 2. Based on my so far limited understanding of Dagger I am confused as to why every single class that is injected has the singleton annotation on it in the dagger module class's. If I was creating this application without dagger they would not all be singletons, is this something specific to dagger or have the previous developers simply misused Dagger?

Comment: It's been a while since I used Dagger but I don't recall turning everything into singletons, so I would guess your hunch of developer abuse is right

Comment: Why wouldn't they all be singletons? Is there an issue with that? I mean, if your objects retain no state, why should there be multiple instances of them? When you say without dagger do you mean without the library or without dependency injection at all?

Comment: @Fred I think there are limited scenarios where singletons are suitable to use and certainly every class should not be one. In my experience they can lead to suitable and nasty bugs because of there global nature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] every single class that is injected has the singleton annotation [...] is this something specific to dagger [...]?

Nope. `@Singleton` is the only scope included with Dagger by default, but you can also create custom scopes, use `@Reusable` which may create multiple objects but will reuse them if possible, or no scope at all.

> or have the previous developers simply misused Dagger?

If possible you should just ask them. If every object is a Singleton this looks like they did not invest a lot of thought in the setup and just copy-pasted declarations, at least this would be my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

From the section about `Reusable` in [the user guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html):

> Sometimes you want to limit the number of times an @Inject-constructed
>   class is instantiated or a @Provides method is called, but you don’t
>   need to guarantee that the exact same instance is used during the
>   lifetime of any particular component or subcomponent. This can be
>   useful in environments such as Android, where allocations can be
>   expensive.

Two main differences:

1. `@Singleton` annotated class is guaranted to give always the same instance. It is needed if we keep global state in it. `@Reusable` do not give any guarantee.
2. If any class requests the instance of `@Singleton` annotated class, [double checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) is performed (which is slow). In case of `@Reusable`, it isn't.

I'd use `@Reusable` scope for classes that are expensive to build (for example I'm using for `Retrofit` instance - but to be honest I've never made performance tests if it is worth to use this annotation at all).

On the other hand, I'm using `@Singleton` annotated class for the cache.

Also, if you have class which keeps encapsulated global state like this:

```
class StateWrapper {
  final State state;
  @Inject
  StateWrapper(State state) {
    this.state = state;
  }
}
```

I mean the state is *de facto* kept in the `State` class, do not annotate `StateWrapper` as `@Singleton`, always annotate the smallest part: in this case the `State` class. 
(This hint is taken from the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBrhRvhF00k))