# Singleton Class, Annotation

Tags: spring, maven, annotations, singleton, lombok

I want to create a lot of **Singleton** classes in my project,
Can anyone guide me **how to create an Annotation that will do my task**?

Similar to Lombok do like @Getter, by using this my getters methods are created at compile time

Same, I want
to create a static instance, private constructor, and static method as `getInstance(){ }`

```
public class AgeValidation{
     -----
     -----
}
```

**I want to make it as Singleton with an annotation:**

```
public class AgeValidation {
```

This is a boilerPlate Code for me:

```
private static final AgeValidation instance = new AgeValidation();

private AgeValidation() { }

public static AgeValidation getInstance() {
 return instance;
 }
}
```

Comment: ALL Spring beans are by default Singletons. You should take some time to read the documentation/some tutorial as this is literally Spring 101

Answer (score 0):

If you are building project using Spring Boot, you can easily specify singleton as [scope](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes) for your bean classes.
Alternatively, you can also experiment with [Dagger 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48163367/dagger-2-and-use-of-singleton) dependency to get annotation @Singleton that will almost do the same thing.